# how can I find all of the indexes associated with an Elastic search alias?

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

using elastic search SDK https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html   how can find all of the indexes associated with an Elastic search  alias

We do have sdk method cat. aliases where I can iterate and find the associated indexes. But is there any other elegant method available to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the alias name (or array of names) as a parameter. [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_cat_aliases)

```
const { Client } = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");
var client;

client = new Client({
  node: "http://localhost:9200",
  maxRetries: 5,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  sniffOnStart: true,
});

client.cat
  .aliases({ format: "json", name: "alias_name" })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.body);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    alias: 'alias_name',
    index: 'index_name',
    filter: '-',
    'routing.index': '-',
    'routing.search': '-',
    is_write_index: '-'
  }
]
```

And if you want the index names only

```
const { Client } = require("@elastic/elasticsearch");
var client;

client = new Client({
  node: "http://localhost:9200",
  maxRetries: 5,
  requestTimeout: 60000,
  sniffOnStart: true,
});

client.cat
  .aliases({ format: "json", name: "alias_name" })
  .then((result) => {
    const clean_indices = result.body.map(r => r.index)
    console.log(clean_indices);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: yeah, i have also done the same thing added alias name also. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with now.

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const async = require('async');
var client;

client = new Client({
    "node": "http://localhost:9200",
    "maxRetries": 5,
    "requestTimeout": 60000,
    "sniffOnStart": true
});

client.cat.aliases({format:"json"}).then((result) => {
let indexes={};
result.body.forEach(element => {
    if(!indexes[element.alias]){
        indexes[element.alias] = [];
    }
    indexes[element.alias].push(element.index);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(indexes,null,2));
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```